# How to assign wallets with different roles?

Tags: solana-program

I want to create a program where I can assign different wallets with different role. For example:

- Wallet 1: Player A
- Wallet 2: Player B
- Wallet 3: Referee

How might I go about implementing a program on Solana to have such a behavior?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.